# How to include a non NPM package in package.json to be installed?

Tags: javascript, npm

I have installed what cloned what looks like a non NPM package https://github.com/anthonygore/html-critical-webpack-plugin into my node_modules directory and then manually ran `npm install` from within to install dependencies. This all works fine locally, I'm just not sure how I can make this module available by possibly including in `package.json` for other developers to pull and install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

package.json

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "html-critical-webpack-plugin": "https://github.com/anthonygore/html-critical-webpack-plugin"
    }
}
```